# Docker with Rust - Different behavior on different platforms?

Tags: docker, rust

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.72

WORKDIR /usr/src/log-signing-mpc
COPY . .

RUN cargo build --release

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/log-signing-mpc/target/release/log-signing-mpc"]
```

Running `docker build -t log-signing-mpc .` on my Windows machine creates an image without error.

However, when running the same thing in GitHub actions

```
name: build-and-unit-tests

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build -t log-signing-mpc .
```

I get compilation error:

```
Err(status::Forbidden(Some("Keys could NOT be generated")))
#11 288.6     |             ----------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&str`, found `Option<&str>`
```

It is a `rocket::response::status`, and I use "0.5.0-rc.2" version of Rocket.

How is that possible when I use the same version of the compiler inside Docker? Should not Docker prevent this behavior? It is not a problem with branches; I run both commands on the same branches.

Minimal working example:

main.rs

```
use rocket::response::status;
fn function() -> Result<&'static str, status::Forbidden<&'static str>> {
    Err(status::Forbidden(Some("Keys could NOT be generated")))
}

fn main() {
    function().expect("");
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "log-signing-mpc"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.2"}
```

I can also tell that the issue is probably in the "0.5.0-rc.2" because when I upgraded to "0.5.0-rc.4", the compiler now detects the error even on Windows.

UPDATE: They must have somewhat changed the runners for GitHub Actions because other things are failing in my pipeline, too. For example, I cannot install the `aiohttp` Python package.

Comment: It is possible that it is compiled on different cpu arch. Which can result in different compilation process, dependencies can even have different apis.

Comment: it would be great if you could provide a minimal working code example

Comment: @LielFridman I added a minimal working example into the description.

Comment: But @freakish might be closer to the issue that it is an architecture problem and not an OS problem because the actions were working one day and stopped working the other without any other changes.

Comment: @user680891 I guess it's better to use rc 4 if you can, and just get rid of the `Some`. It makes more sense in my opinion

Comment: @LielFridman I will definitely do that, although it is still weird that this problem occurs even with Docker (the target platform is the same, I only compile it on two distinct ones).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation approach:

1. You have not committed the `Cargo.lock` file.
2. You're using `0.5.0-rc.2` locally, where it's [`struct Forbidden<R>(Option<R>)`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.2/rocket/response/status/struct.Forbidden.html)
3. On GHA, cargo regenerates the lock file and upgrades to `0.5.0-rc.4`, where it's [`struct Forbidden<R>(R)`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.4/rocket/response/status/struct.Forbidden.html), resulting in the error above.

Stop using RCs, commit the lock file (and make sure it's not in `.dockerignore`), and/or specify the dependency as `rocket = "=0.5.0-rc.2"`.